# MPAndroidChart setValueFormatter requires ValueFormater not IAxisValueFormatter

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart

so basicly recently I started programming mobile apps and found a problem in my application. I want XAxis values of my line chart in 19:30 format, not 3244 minutes passed format, so I googled AxisFormatters. The problem is, in all of the tutorials they make class like this:

```
private class MyAxisFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return value as an hour;
    }
}
```

and then put it in function:

```
    XAxis valAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    valAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyAxisFormatter());
```

But whenever I impement it into this I got red underline saying: Required type:
ValueFormatter
Provided:
MyAxisFormatter

I tried to cast it somehow to ValueFormatter but that didnt work, solution that program prompts me is to make MyAxisFormater extend ValueFormatter although i dont get any errors then that doesnt change any value on my XAxis

Answer (score 3):

Ok I got it, instead of using

```
private class MyAxisFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
 @Override
 public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
     return value as an hour;
 }
}
```

I used

```
private class MyAxisFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return "someValue";
    }
}
```

And everything works fine